# How to add an openai API key in a weaviate GraphQL command on the cloud console?

Tags: weaviate

I want to do a similiarity search like this:

```
{
  Get {
    ResultItem(
      limit:3
      nearText: {concepts: ["hacking attack on company"]}
    ) {
      title, url, snippet
    }
  }
}
```

This gives me the following error:
"explorer: get class: vectorize params: vectorize params: vectorize params: vectorize keywords: remote client vectorize: API Key: no api key found neither in request header: `X-Openai-Api-Key nor in environment variable under OPENAI_APIKEY"`,

The given string has to be vectorized in my case with openai. But how can I add the neccessary API key in the command on the cloud console?

In the weaviate cloud console where you can query your database I tried the above mentioned query. I expected to get max 3 results with their title, url and snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it in the header section as outlined [here](https://weaviate.io/developers/wcs/guides/console#inference-keys)

[image: Weaviate Console API-keys]

Comment: I didn't see the headers tab at the bottom. Thank you!